# Issues with Joins where joins are reliant on 2 conditions - SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

[Image - click here for sample data tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnoh3.png)

I have attached an image of the tables and some sample data and I am trying to create a query that returns the following in the select statement, but am getting a bit confused and don't seem to be able to quite get the joins and where clauses right.

```
OFF_HIRES.Off_Hire_ID,
HIRE_CONTRACTS.Contract_Number,
MOBILE_JOB.MBW_Completed_Time,
Collection Charge - (This is the sum of the Charge_Amount for each HIRE_ITEMS.Contract_Number 
   where the HIRE_ITEMS.Stock_Number = 'COLLECTION' ),
TOTAL WEIGHT - (This is the sum of the STOCK_ITEMS.Weight * OFF_HIRE_ITEMS.QTY_OFF_HIRED)
```

The Links between the tables are as follows

```
OFF_HIRES.Contract_Number = Hire_Contracts.Contract_Number
OFF_HIRES.Off_hire_ID = OFF_HIRE_ITEMS.Off_hire_ID
HIRE_CONTRACTS.Contract_Number = HIRE_ITEMS.Contract_Number
HIRE_ITEMS.Stock_Number = STOCK_ITEMS.Stock_Number
MOBILE_JOB.Mbw_Doc_ID = OFF_HIRE_ITEMS.Off_Hire_Conntract_Number
```

and then there is a link between the OFF_HIRE_ITEMS and HIRE_ITEMS but requires both links to be true -
OFF_HIRE_ITEMS.Off_Hire_Contract_Number = HIRE_ITEMS.Contract_Number AND
OFF_HIRE_ITEMS.OH_ITEM_SEQ = HIRE_ITEMS.HIT_SEQ

Answer (score 0):

You data structure is a little mess, but i think i got you:

```
SELECT 
OFF_HIRES.Off_Hire_ID,
HIRE_CONTRACTS.Contract_Number,
(SELECT MOBILE_JOB.MBW_Completed_Time 
FROM Mobile_JOB 
WHERE Mobile_JOB.MB_Doc_ID = OFF_HIRES.Off_HIRE_ID) 'MBW_Completed_Time',
(SELECT SUM(Charge_Amount) 
FROM HIRE_ITEMS 
WHERE HIRE_ITEMS.Contract_Number = OFF_HIRES.Contract_Number 
AND HIRE_ITEMS.Stock_Number = 'COLLECTION') 'SumCollectionCharge',
(SELECT SUM(ISNULL(STOCK_ITEMS.Weight,0) * OFF_HIRE_ITEMS.QTY_OFF_HIRED) 
FROM HIRE_ITEMS 
INNER JOIN OFF_HIRE_ITEMS 
    ON OFF_HIRE_TIEMS.OH_ITEM_SEQ = HIRE_ITEMS.HIT_SEQ 
    AND OFF_HIRE_ITEMS.Off_Hire_Contract_Number = HIRE_ITEMS.Contract_Number
INNER JOIN STOCK_ITEMS
    ON STOCK_ITEMS.Stock_Number = HIRE_ITEMS.Stock_Number
) 'SumTotalWeight'

FROM OFF_Hires
INNER JOIN HIRE_CONTRACTS 
    ON HIRE_CONTRACTS.Contract_Number = OFF_Hires.Contract_Number
```

Comment: There are many other ways for this problem, but sub queries are very usefull if your data realations are bad.